# How to launch an android app as a Service on bootup and then launch an Activity(the UI), when the icon is clicked.

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-input-filter

I have an android app that needs to run in the background at all times, However on receving some kind of user action, I need to launch a new Activity and bring it to front.

Now I have a service 'A', that needs to keep running from when the device boots, and an Activity 'B' that has to be launched when a particular user action is received(Havent decided what yet). How do I go about it?

I will provide an intent-filter for 'B' to specify when it should be launched. But do I have to start it explicitly from the Service as well?

Comment: "I have an android app that needs to run in the background at all times" -- that's rarely a good idea from the user's standpoint.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I'm building this app for an industrial use case where the devices are not assigned to individuals(and therefore will not have very many applications running on it) and therefore I need to send a heartbeat signal to a server to let it know who is using it at the moment.

Comment: "and therefore I need to send a heartbeat signal to a server to let it know who is using it at the moment" -- that can be done with `AlarmManager`, without having "an android app that needs to run in the background at all times".

Comment: Thanks for this input. But even then I'd still like to know if I can start an Activity from a Service when a user action is received?

Comment: Since services are generally incapable of "receiving" a "user action", we need to know the desired "user action" before we can tell you if a service can "receive" it. Services can call `startActivity()`, though this is generally not a good idea, as it will interrupt the user in whatever the user is currently doing.

Comment: The user action I was talking about is when a picture is taken. But I just figured out that I can have a BroadcastReceiver set up and listen to this particular broadcast and start an intent then.

Comment: Coming back to the AlarmManager however, the heartbeat signal that I was talking about earlier that I need to send to a server periodically; I need it to run in the background and not have any impact on the UI. But with AlarmManager, when I start the intent associated with sending this signal, the application is brought to the foreground, is there a way to avoid that.